# Part line attribute

Tags: postgis

I have a PostGIS database with linear objects: cables. Can I add attributes describing only part of the entire cable? For example, the total length of the cable is 10 km, and I want to add a red color from 1.5 km to 5 km.

I know that is linear referencing function, but it writes the distance relatively as a percentage of the length, but not as the distance from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Linear referencing in PostGIS only supports fractions. So in this case, determining the parts can be done by using ([ST_Line_Substring](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Line_Substring.html)) and querying as follows:

```
Select ST_ASText(ST_Line_Substring(line.geom,
                        (1.5-0)/st_length(line.geom)
                        , (5-0)/st_length(line.geom))) from line;
```

> This solution works by assuming the change in the distance just in one direction, Where 1.5 is the desired beginning of the part, and 5 is the desired end length of
>   the part. And the start point is 0.

What I did above is just to convert the beginning length and end length of the part to fractions.

[image]